How to Set a Custom PNG Image as a Splash Screen on Android 12+ (API 31+)?
As I understand, from Android 12 (API 31+) the correct way to set the SplashScreen of the app is via the androidX core SplashScreen library:
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">

   <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/icon</item>
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>

   <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App</item>
</style>

Is there a way to set a custom PNG image for devices with Android 12+ installed? The approach described above will not work since I have a complex custom background for the SplashScreen.

tried THAT?

@snachmsm yes, but it doesn't work for me

looks like you can't, you can set only solid color, for consistency... windowSplashScreenBackground takes only color resource, no drawables
best you can do is keep gradient for older devices, but API31+ is pretty common nowadays
or keep lower target API (30), but this will limit you e.g. with publishing in Play Store
similar SO question
